# Is the JavaScript ES6 promise exactly the same as Promise/A+?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I can find some blog posts stating that JavaScript ES6's promise is Promise/A+, but [the official ES6 specs](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-constructor) doesn't mention it, and [MDN has a link to Promise/A+ at the very bottom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), but didn't state that ES6 JavaScript's promise is exactly the same as Promise/A+.

Sometimes it is stated as "ES6 promise is *based on* Promise/A+", but are they exactly the same? ( is it mentioned in official docs, such as from ECMA or MDN?)

Comment: Promises/A+ only specifies `then`. It doesn't specify how promises are constructed, that there's a `Promise` class, the other methods besides `then`, how callbacks are scheduled exactly, that thenable resolution is asynchronous as well, and much more.

Answer (score 7):

They aren't *identical*, but JavaScript's promises are fully compliant with the Promises/A+ specification.

Promises/A+ is intentionally minimalist. JavaScript's promises have utility features that aren't covered by the Promises/A+ spec (such as `catch` and `finally`). Those are implemented using only features covered by Promises/A+, though. For instance, `catch` and `finally` are implemented via calls to `then`. (*Literally*, not just conceptually.) If you look at [the specification for `catch`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-promise.prototype.catch) for example, it says `catch` is literally this:

```
class Promise {
    // ...

    catch(onRejected) {
        return this.then(undefined, onRejected);
    }

    // ...
}
```

(`finally` is a bit more complex, but it too ends up calling `then` and returning the promise it creates.)

JavaScript's promises also have the occasional optimization that only works if a native promise (instead of a promise from a third-party library) is used, but again, they're fully compliant with Promises/A+.

Answer (score 0):

The EcmaScript `Promise` constructor produces promises that are fully Promises/A+ compliant. They obey all the rules in the [Promises/A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/).

The inverse is not true. A Promises/A+ compliant implementation of promises is not necessarily compliant with the EcmaScript specification, even when we focus only on the `then` method, which is what the Promises/A+ specification really is about (for instance, the latter does not specify how promises should be *created*).

Some examples:

### 1. Which Job Queue?

Section 3.1 of the Promises/A+ specification gives some details about how implementations could schedule the asynchronous jobs that emerge from promises:

> This can be implemented with either a “macro-task” mechanism such as `setTimeout` or `setImmediate`, or with a “micro-task” mechanism such as `MutationObserver` or `process.nextTick`. Since the promise implementation is considered platform code, it may itself contain a task-scheduling queue or “trampoline” in which the handlers are called.

But the EcmaScript specification is more specific on this. It defines the [PromiseJobs queue](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues) exclusively used for this purpose, and so an implementation that would instead use the same queue as the one used by `setTimeout` would violate this requirement.

### 2. Order of Execution

Although the Promises/A+ specification requires an order of execution of the callbacks that are provided to multiple `then` methods on the *same* promise (see 2.6.6), it does not set an order of execution when it concerns *different* promises.

To illustrate:

```js
let promiseA = Promise.resolve(1);
let promiseB = Promise.resolve(2);
promiseA.then(console.log);
promiseB.then(console.log);
```

Here the output is 1 and 2, but a Promises/A+ compliant implementation could (for some odd reason) bring about the reverse output. That would not be compliant with the EcmaScript specification, but still with the Promises/A+ specification.

### 3. When to schedule a Resolve event?

Yet another example can be found in [Why is a new promise resolved earlier with p.then(resolve) than with resolve(p)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54202637/5459839)